# In $\Delta ABC$, $\frac{b+c}{a}\le \csc A/2$, then $\csc^n A/2 \csc^n B/2 \csc^n C/2=2^{kn}$ for all integer $n\ge 1$, find $k$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n=1$

$$\frac ba + \frac ca \le \csc A/2$$

So for the given expression

$$ (\frac ba +\frac ca)(\frac ab +\frac cb)(\frac ac +\frac bc)\ge 2^k$$

Had all the operations been $+$ I would have used $AM\ge GM$. I know we have to use it somewhere, because I have solved this before but can’t remember how I did it. What should be the next step ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{b+c}2=\dfrac{2\cos\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac{B-C}2}{2\sin\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac A2}$$

So ,we  need $$\cos\dfrac{B-C}2\le1$$  which is a tuatology

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don’t remember it being this complicated. I am confident

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I solved the question myself

$$\csc \frac A2 \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{bc}{a^2}}$$

It’s similar for all angles $B$ and $C$

So 
$$\csc \frac A2 \csc \frac B2 \csc \frac C2 \ge 2^3$$

So $k=3$